# How to force a ListBox to reload data in WinForm

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I have a ListBox on a Windows Form  that is populated during the Form_Load event like so.

```
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SA.Business.ComputerList computerList;
        computerList = SA.Business.Business.GetComputerList();

        this.lbComputers.DataSource = computerList;
        this.lbComputers.DisplayMember = "Name";
    }
```

The GetComputerList returns a ComputerList Object that inherits from BindingList<>

I have a button on the form that when clicked updates the table that is the source of the data for the ComputerList Object.

After it is done updating I just want to force the ListBox to repoulate itself with the fresh data from the DB.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Abstract your loading code into a separate function, then call that function from your Form_Load and also from your button click event.

Answer (score 0):

this should work..

```
// after the code to update the source
Form1_Load(null, null);
```